# How to show a message on a certain number count using parseInt (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, parseint

Hello :) Using parseInt I made a function that counts how many times you've clicked a certain button. Now I want to adjust this function or create another function that will show a message at a certain amount of clicks. 
This is how I count the clicks:

```
var cnt=0;
function CountBats(){
 cnt=parseInt(cnt)+parseInt(1);
 var divData=document.getElementById("showBats");
 divData.innerHTML="Total number of bats: "+cnt +"";
};
```

This is what I thought would show a message, but it doesn't work:

```
var cn=0;
function Nice(){
    cn=parseInt(cn)+parseInt(1);
    var divNice=document.getElementById("Nice");
    if (cn = 1) { 
    divNice.style.animation="nice 2s ease-out alternate 2";
    divNice.innerHTML="Nice!";}};
```

It did work when I put the if statement inside the counting function, but the problem with that was that the counter stopped after the button had been clicked twice. Question is, how do I make this work? (NB: I would like to do this in javascript, not jquery)
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

It might be because you did

```
if (cn = 1)
```

Instead of

```
if (cn == 1)
```

With only one =, you just set the cn to 1. With ==, you're checking if they're equal.

Comment: Oh that was it! I completely overlooked it. Thanks, it works now :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `parseInt` for this, also your logical equality operator is wrong.

Your refactored code should be:

```
var cn = 0;
function Nice() {
    cn++; // Read more about the ++ operator
    var divNice = document.getElementById("Nice");
    if (cn === 1) { 
    divNice.style.animation="nice 2s ease-out alternate 2";
    divNice.innerHTML="Nice!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You were using `=` instead of ´==´ to compare.

- You do not have to use `ParseInt` in this case

```js
var cn = 0;
var divNice = document.getElementById("Nice");

function Nice() {
  cn++;
  if (cn == 1) {
    divNice.style.animation = "nice 2s ease-out alternate 2";
    divNice.innerHTML = "Nice!";
  }
};
```

```html
<button onclick="Nice()">Click me</button>
<div id="Nice"></div>
```